# Subset of a finite set is finite: base step

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

We can prove by induction that any subset of a finite step is finite. But I am confused by the step "Observe first that all subsets of $\emptyset$ and $\mathbf I_1$ are finite", which I think is the base step of the induction.

A set is finite if its elements can be put into bijection with $\mathbf I_n$, where n is a positive integer and $\mathbf I_n = \{1, 2, ..., n\}$. $\emptyset$ is finite by definition, and vacuously, its subsets are finite. The single element of $\mathbf I_1$ can be put into bijection with $\mathbf I_1$, so $\mathbf I_1$ is finite. The only other subset of $\mathbf I_1$ is $\emptyset$, which again is finite.

Do we show that all subsets of $\emptyset$ are finite because the empty set cannot be included in the induction, or is it part of the base step?

Comment: Your second paragraph begins with an incorrect definition of "finite."  A set is finite if its elements can be put in bijection with $I_n$ where $n$ is a *non-negative* integer.  That is, $n$ is allowed to be $0$, in which case $I_n$ would be empty.  With the definition you gave, requiring $n$ to be positive, it would not be the case that all subsets of finite sets are finite.

Comment: Wouldn't defining the empty set as finite take care of this problem? Though the definition you are using seems more elegant (I can find both definitions on internet sources). Thanks.

Comment: Defining the empty set as finite would take care of the problem, and that's exactly what I did by correcting "positive" to "non-negative".